# convert date rows into columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data as per the below. I need to convert the date rows into columns and need to populate count of contracts in the respective dates. Please help to arrive the code.
This is the Data in the table XXX
[image]

Expected output is

[image]

Please do needful

this is the code I have tried. But got error for the data type.

```
    DECLARE @Proposed_Delv_Dt AS datetime
SELECT @Proposed_Delv_Dt = 
    COALESCE(@Proposed_Delv_Dt + ', ', '') +  CAST(@Proposed_Delv_Dt AS datetime)
    FROM ( select distinct Proposed_Delv_Dt from (select  PM.Project_Alias_name as 'Project Name', CD.Key_column_values as contractNumber, PLM.Type_of_picklist as Lease_type, 
PLM.Pick_List_description as TypeOfWork, PWS.Workflow_status_description as Contract_status,
  UM.Employee_id, SM.SBU_Name, UM.fULL_NAME as Assigned_To, UMAB.Full_Name as 
assigned_By, RM.Role_Description as role, CUD.Change_date as AssignedDate, CD.Proposed_delivery_date as 'Proposed_Delv_Dt'
from Contract_user_details CUD
left join Contract_Details CD on CD.Pkey = CUD.Fkey_Contract_Key
left join Project_Master PM on CD.Fkey_Project_Key = PM.Pkey
left join SBU_Master SM on SM.Pkey = PM.Fkey_Sbu_key
left join Pick_list_master PLM on CD.Fkey_Lease_Type = PLM.Pkey
left join Project_Workflow_Status PWS on CD.Fkey_Current_Workflow_Status = PWS.Pkey
left join Users_Master UM on CUD.Fkey_User_key = UM.Pkey
left join Users_Master UMAB on CUD.Fkey_assigned_by = UMAB.Pkey
left join Role_master RM on RM.pkey = CUD.Fkey_Role_key)f )d
SELECT @Proposed_Delv_Dt Dates
```

Iam expecting o/p of dates separated by ',' (commas)

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to do counting for the different dates,

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code sharing platform. Please show at least some research effort.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want and I think I'm not alone.

Comment: hi Jean Doux. What I need is the output as per the second Image. I have tried for separating the dates by commas and again use that data for pivot function.

Comment: The first table I have mentioned was arrived by me in from different table by using joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Proposed_Delv_Dt AS NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @Proposed_Delv_Dt = 
    COALESCE(@Proposed_Delv_Dt + ',[ ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Proposed_Delv_Dt], 112) + ']','[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Proposed_Delv_Dt], 112) + ']')
    FROM ( select distinct Proposed_Delv_Dt from (select  PM.Project_Alias_name as 'Project Name', CD.Key_column_values as contractNumber, PLM.Type_of_picklist as Lease_type, 
PLM.Pick_List_description as TypeOfWork, PWS.Workflow_status_description as Contract_status,
UM.Employee_id, SM.SBU_Name,UM.fULL_NAME as Assigned_To, UMAB.Full_Name as 
assigned_By, RM.Role_Description as role, CUD.Change_date as AssignedDate, CD.Proposed_delivery_date as Proposed_Delv_Dt
from Contract_user_details CUD
left join Contract_Details CD on CD.Pkey = CUD.Fkey_Contract_Key
left join Project_Master PM on CD.Fkey_Project_Key = PM.Pkey
left join SBU_Master SM on SM.Pkey = PM.Fkey_Sbu_key
left join Pick_list_master PLM on CD.Fkey_Lease_Type = PLM.Pkey
left join Project_Workflow_Status PWS on CD.Fkey_Current_Workflow_Status = PWS.Pkey
left join Users_Master UM on CUD.Fkey_User_key = UM.Pkey
left join Users_Master UMAB on CUD.Fkey_assigned_by = UMAB.Pkey
left join Role_master RM on RM.pkey = CUD.Fkey_Role_key)f )d

DECLARE @DynamicPIVOT AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @DynamicPIVOT = 'SELECT  SBU_name, Contract_status, Assigned_to, Role, ' + @Proposed_Delv_Dt + 
' FROM (
    select  PM.Project_Alias_name as Project_Name, CD.Key_column_values as contractNumber, PLM.Type_of_picklist as Lease_type, 
PLM.Pick_List_description as TypeOfWork, PWS.Workflow_status_description as Contract_status,
UM.Employee_id, SM.SBU_Name,UM.fULL_NAME as Assigned_To, UMAB.Full_Name as 
assigned_By, RM.Role_Description as role, CUD.Change_date as AssignedDate, CD.Proposed_delivery_date as Proposed_Delv_Dt
from Contract_user_details CUD

left join Contract_Details CD on CD.Pkey = CUD.Fkey_Contract_Key
left join Project_Master PM on CD.Fkey_Project_Key = PM.Pkey
left join SBU_Master SM on SM.Pkey = PM.Fkey_Sbu_key
left join Pick_list_master PLM on CD.Fkey_Lease_Type = PLM.Pkey
left join Project_Workflow_Status PWS on CD.Fkey_Current_Workflow_Status = PWS.Pkey
left join Users_Master UM on CUD.Fkey_User_key = UM.Pkey
left join Users_Master UMAB on CUD.Fkey_assigned_by = UMAB.Pkey
left join Role_master RM on RM.pkey = CUD.Fkey_Role_key)f 
PIVOT (
    count(contractNumber) FOR Proposed_Delv_Dt IN (' + @Proposed_Delv_Dt + ')
) Result;'

EXEC (@DynamicPIVOT)
```

I have arrived from the above code... But i have only one issue. I need a grand total as the lost column which has sum of count in the date column as below.
[image]

Also I need to group by SbU_name,contract_status,Assigned_to, Role